# Chart JS dynamic chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am using `Chart.js` to build a dynamic chart (the same canvas element shows data for 30 days, 7 days and 1 day depending on the value of a drop down.

I have the code working as far as redrawing the canvas. The new data appears on drop down change, but when I mouse over the chart the data flickers and I can see the previous version of the chart. I know I need to use the `.clear()` function to clear the data, but I'm not sure where this should happen. On var `ctx` before the function is executed? Or on
 `window.myLine`?

```
function redrawChart(data){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
        responsive: true
    });
}
```

Comment: I have encountered the same problem and I tried to use .clear(), .destroy(), .remove(), none of those works. In the end I choose to use Google chart.

Comment: I never found a solution either, but the "flickering" issue stopped when I disabled the hover effects on the points. I've been considering switching to Google Charts as well.

Comment: Try my Solution , Hope it may be helpful, its working for me

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

Before binding data , remove the canvas too ;)

HTML:

```
<div id="DivChartContainer"></div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
        $('#DivChartContainer').empty();
        $('#DivChartContainer').append('<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>');
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
            responsive: true,
            barValueSpacing: 10,
            barStrokeWidth: 0,
            scaleShowLabels: true,
            scaleShowGridLines: true,
            scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
            scaleGridLineWidth: 1,
        });
```

Issue Solved !!

Comment: The reason you're having trouble with .destroy is your chart is stored as a var. Try window.myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar and you'll find it works. I worked it out thanks to another commenter below.

Comment: @Suganth G i want to set current month all the dates on y ex in charts so can you please help me how can do that.

Answer (score 2):

destroy() works fine for me, check this code.

```
 if (window.myDoughnut)
     window.myDoughnut.destroy();

 var ctx = $elm.getContext("2d");
 window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx).DoughnutAlt(value, {showScale: true, scaleShowLabels: true, animation: false});
```

Comment: This is what I was missing, using window to keep the graph alive. Using var meant it's gone after function call. Thank you.

Comment: Although once you've created the graph with 
window.myDoughnut = new Chart.... you don't need to use window. to reference it, you can just use myDoughnut.destroy()

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues with .clear() and .destroy()

What worked for me:

> completely remove and replace the `<canvas>` element